# Is making a sandbox feasible in Godot/Unity (w/o open world)?

Tags: unity, godot

I want to make a 3D multiplayer game. It will inherit the basic principles of the MOBA genre: players choose from the variety of characters each having 4-8 unique abilities, then battle it out. I also want some abilities to affect terrain.

I try to keep the concept simple to be able to make this game alone. It would be good if I manage to finish the first playable prototype in no more than 6 months (keeping in mind that I'll be able to work on the game mostly on weekends). Multiplayer AND 3d in themselves make things much harder, so deciding which mechanics to implement and how is essential. Thus I want to make sure I won't have to redo much after I start programming.

To implement the destructible terrain I decided to stick with a Minecraft-ish approach, where everything consists of blocks. The sandbox is a very hard genre in terms of game development, but after doing quick research, I concluded that most difficulties arise from the fact that the game is open-world. This isn't my case. I won't need too many blocks to construct the arenas.

Now I need to come up with the engine I'm gonna use. I like Godot due to its development paradigm, but I'm not sure whether it is a good choice for a game like this. Maybe Unity is the better choice in my situation. Or something else.

Maybe I need to remove some mechanics from the concept to make the development a lot faster.

Can you comment on it? Thanks!

P. S. I have 7 years' programming experience (with Haxe and Python being my main languages) and a good mathematical background. I have been developing my multiplayer game for 3 years now (**but it is a 2D game**, I have no experience in 3d gamedev beyond the Godot tutorial). It is okay if I need to learn different things before starting to make a game, but I want to make the learning process as effective as possible.

Comment: Is making a sandbox feasible in Godot/Unity (w/o open world)? Yes. *Why a yes/no question?* My opinion: I don't know about the time limitation. It might not be realistic if you are working alone. Extra comment: if you separate the mechanics in a core that does not have engine specific code, you can easily port that core from Godot to Unity or viceversa, as they both work with C#. *I have done something like that in the past.* You won't move all of the code, you will need classes with the responsibility to plug parts of your core to the game engine (binding events and talking to engine types).

Comment: I think it's feasible with godot, but I'm not an expert.  Maybe you should take it a step at a time.  For instance, first step, make one playable character.  then add multiplayer so two people can fight with two of the same character.  Next add another character, and another etc.  Than if you still want to, work on giving the ability to edit terrain.  If you take this step by step approach, it might be easier to implement and find tutorials, obviously the steps are just suggestions, others might work better for you.  hope it helps, and good luck!

Comment: ok, apparently this got closed because of some dumb rule about not asking what program you should use.  (there is a *lot* of rules.)  Godot can definitely handle multiplayer, and the fighting gameplay.  And people have made voxel gameplay with godot, there are even plugins that implement it for you.  The one issue is that people say it's better to use C++ for voxels, however if you are not doing an open world, and work hard to optimize, I think GDscript will be fine.  good luck, and happy game development!  =D